# How to import PouchDroid library into android studio from github?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, pouchdb

I am new to PouchDroid. I am developing and offline android application.

I want to add PouchDroid to my project. I have already followed this steps  [How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-android-studio).

But every time I will get below error.

Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Comment: may be this link will help : https://github.com/nolanlawson/PouchDroid/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: @AADTechnical even that link also tried but did not work